# How host the ASP Websites with Database?

Tags: sql, asp.net, azure

I have developed asp website using Visual Studio and i have SQL Database designed in SQL Management Studio. My query is how to deploy my website along with the database in Web.

Comment: Just find hosting provider that support ASP.NET. Then you just need to upload your files to your hosting provider and also the datbase

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this with `Azure` and `Visual Studio`, I'm laying out the most common and simple scenario:

- [Deploying your `ASP` website with `visual studio` to an `Azure` `App Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-get-started)
- [Deploying your `SQL` database to `Azure SQL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-cloud-migrate)
- [Connecting your `ASP` website to `Azure SQL` with connection string](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-5-Connect-to-SQL-ffdd5830)

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy a Web Project Using One-Click Publish in Visual Studio

More details here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx